# query on diagonalizabiblity of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
Here I found options 2 & 3 to be false. Its answer is option d .How come A is diagonalizable? And how minimal polynomial is not equal to characteristic eqn . Please explain.

Comment: all symmetric (real) matrices are diagonalizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\chi(\lambda)=\lambda^2(\lambda-3a)$. Being $A$ diagonalizable, its minimum polynomial is necessarily $\mu(\lambda)=\lambda^1 (\lambda-3a)^1$ if $a\ne 0 $ and $\mu(\lambda)=\lambda^1$ if $a=0$ so, $\mu(\lambda)\ne \chi(\lambda).$